# Excel combine rows dollar amount with matching row values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I've ran into a problem with Excel, I have the below table

[image]

Basically, I'm trying to figure out how to make all rows that have the same product key combine, except calculating the dollar amount for each matching row for that new row. For example, rows 8 and 9 would match on row E, and then add 3.99 and 7.99. The result would be only one row with all the same information except for Dollars which would be 11.98.

Can anyone help me figure out how to go about doing this?

Comment: Did you try using Pivot tables?

Comment: A problem directly addressed by Pivot Table, as @DaveRook mentioned

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a job for [pivot table](https://support.office.com/client/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)!

Highlight your table and go to Insert → pivot table and arrange it how you want. I'd do the following -

[image]

Comment: What a wonderfully clear answer...

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the pivot table/report is the way to go. But if you would rather have the results below the table, you can use the [`SUMIFS function`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA010047504.aspx) to total the dollars which meets the product key criteria in the range you specify. You can use multiple criteria if needed.

> SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2,
>   criteria2], …)

Below I used the example to build subtotals below the table.

[image]

Here it is again with the formula highlights.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without Pivot table, to get your result (as far I understand your need) :

[image: Result]

Enter thoses formulas :

in G row: =IF(E2=C1;E1;0)+F2

in H row: =IF(E2=E3;"";G2)

(then you could hide the G row)